# How to filtering pandas dataframe by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I would like to get values from column `n` where values in subset of other columns is True.
Example, the data frame:

```py
t, f = True, False
data = [
 [t, f, f, '1'],
 [f, f, f, '2'],
 [f, t, f, '3'],
 [f, f, t, '4']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list("abcn"))
```

df as table

```
       a      b      c  n
0   True  False  False  1
1  False  False  False  2
2  False   True  False  3
3  False  False   True  4
```

columns for search is `a` and `b`, and I wish to get records from `n` where these columns are `True`, what I tried:

```py
fcols = ("a", "b")
df[df[[*fcols]] == t].dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

this is give me right records, but with `Nan` in the column `n`

```
      a     b    c    n
0  True   NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  True  NaN  NaN
```

I'm feel that I'm more or less close to the solution, but ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to aggregate the booleans for your [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
fcols = ("a", "b")

out = df[df[[*fcols]].eq(t).any(axis=1)]#.dropna(axis=0, how='all') # dropna not needed
```

Output:

```
       a      b      c  n
0   True  False  False  1
2  False   True  False  3
```

Intermediate indexing Series:

```
df[[*fcols]].eq(t).any(axis=1)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided in this way

```py
df = df[df['a'] | df['b']]

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
       a      b      c  n
0   True  False  False  1
2  False   True  False  3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
but using tuple is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` match per rows for boolean Series passed to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
fcols = ("a", "b")
df = df[df[[*fcols]].eq(t).any(axis=1)]

#if need test Trues, possible remove compare by True
df = df[df[[*fcols]].any(axis=1)]

print (df)
       a      b      c  n
0   True  False  False  1
2  False   True  False  3
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[[*fcols]].eq(t).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```